# Sum of entries of $W^k$ in terms of limiting spectral density of $W$?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, random-matrices

Suppose $h$ is spectrum of a random matrix $M$ and $e$ is a vector valued time-series in $\mathbb{R}^d$ with $d\approx \infty$, which starts with $(1,1,\ldots,1)$ and updates $i$'th component at each step as follows

$$e_i \leftarrow e_i - 2 h_i e_i + h_i \langle h, e\rangle  $$

Is there a way to express $\|e\|_1$ at time $t$ in terms of of limiting spectral density of $M$?

Thomas Trogdon [shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJM1k.png) how to represent $\|e\|_1$ in terms of empirical spectral density in "Random Matrix Theory" [tutorial](https://random-matrix-learning.github.io/pdf/part3.pdf), but I'm unclear how to extend this to the limiting spectral density.

Motivation: to characterize behavior of stochastic gradient descent for a random linear problem. Analogous to RMT approach analyzing (non-stochastic) gradient descent as done [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.04299).